# AucTeX: Can not include selected text into LaTeX environment

Tags: auctex

In earlier versions of emacs (<23, I believe), when a region ( e.g., 'some text') was selected in AucTeX, and C-e was entered to include the text an environment, the following was obtained:

```
\begin{center}
some text
\end{center}
```

However, in Emacs 24, it is not possible to use C-e if a region has been selected. Rather, I have to unselect the region and then type C-e. If the point is on the text, the environment is inserted after the text with C-e:

```
some text
\begin{center}

\end{center}
```

and the cursor is within the environment.

Is it possible to get the old behaviour back?

Comment: The feature you describe works also with Emacs 24, so probably you have some settings in your init file preventing this from working.

Comment: Thank you. I found the culprit: `'(cua-mode t nil (cua-base))`

Comment: You may want to answer your own question then `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

The selected text does not seem to be included if cua-mode is turned on, so it needs to be turned off:

```
(cua-mode 0)
```